# How to import turicreate to anaconda's python so that i can use it in spyder IDE

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, spyder, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I used Windows 10 (WSL Ubuntu) to download and install turicreate in a virtual envirnoment. but i have no idea how to import it to anaconda. whenever i import turicreate from spyder i get the message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'turicreate'.